# Understanding trigonometric identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can someone help me understand trigonometric identities? For example, it is known that $\cos(90-\theta)$ is equal to $\sin \theta$, and vice versa. But why? Is it something to do with the unit circle? Is it visual?

Comment: For $0 < \theta < \pi/2$ you can think of a right triangle. The identity is clear for $\cos(\pi/2 - \theta) = \sin (\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
\[ \sin(90^{\circ})=1 \]
\[ \cos(90^{\circ})=0 \]
\[ \cos(\alpha - \beta)= \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\]
Then
\[
\cos(90^{\circ}-\theta)=\cos(90^{\circ} )\cos(\theta)+\sin(90^{\circ})\sin\theta =0\cdot\cos(\theta)+1\cdot\sin\theta=\sin\theta
\]

Answer (score 4):

Using the formula $$\cos{(a-b)}=\sin{a}\sin{b}+\cos{a}\cos{b}$$
we get:
$$\cos{(90^{\circ}-\theta)}=\sin{90^{\circ}}\sin{\theta}+\cos{90^{\circ}}\cos{\theta}=1 \cdot \sin{\theta}+0 \cdot \cos{\theta}=\sin{\theta}$$

Answer (score 2):

Take a right triangle $ABC$ with $\angle B=90^\circ$ and $\angle A=\theta$. Then $\sin\theta = \frac{BC}{CA}=\cos \angle C=\cos (90^\circ-\theta)$.